# Get the word from sentence that match to an array PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

Currently I have this variable in `php`

```
   @if(count($label_types) > 0)
   @foreach ($label_types as $label_type)
      @if($label_type)
        {{ $label_type->fldLabelTypeName }}
      @endif
   @endforeach
   @endif
```

Which contains the following rows

`Waterproof (This is waterproof)`

`Glossy`

`Normal`

Now since `waterproof has the (This is waterproof)` on the records

Now I want to only return the words that matches with these keywords

`waterproof`, `glossy`, `normal`

whether they are `uppercases`, `lowercases`

For example if the case is : `waterproofss` with double `s`

the return would be `waterproof`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using regex. First, you need to map your cases on string-like key `waterprofs|waterproffs|waterproffss` and value `Waterproof` for these cases. Your mapped key will work as a pattern in a regex. [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will check your pattern in your string. if the pattern matched, then it will return its value which one you defined in your map.

```
function getLabel(string $string)
{
    // You own custom map using regex, key-value pair,
    $matchersMap = [
        'waterproofs|waterproof' => 'Waterproof',
        'glossies|glossy' => 'Glossy',
        'normal' => 'Normal'
    ];

    $result = -1;

    foreach($matchersMap as $matchesKey => $replaceValue) {
        if (preg_match("/$matchesKey/", strtolower($string))) {
            $result = $replaceValue;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

var_dump(getLabel("waterproof has the (This is waterproof)")); //Waterproof
```

Hopefully, you will get a minimum idea of how you will show your desired value by using regex.